# Routing to different function based on login

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can i call the different function based on the login. I have a user login it should check whether the user is employee or student stored on the database on user_type.

I have a controller with two functions:

```
class mainextends CI_Controller {

function index()
{
    echo "main";
}

function student($user_id)
{
    //code
}

function employee($user_id)
{
    //code
}
```

routes.php:

```
$route['default_controller']   = "main";
$route['people/(.*)']          = "main/student/$1";
$route['trainer/(.*)']         = "main/employee/$1";
$route['404_override']         = '';
```

Where can i check the user_type before redirecting it to appropriate url.

Comment: Post user login too. For now it is too broad for answering without seeing concrete methods you are using for login. Also maybe it would be ok to make two controllers regarding of level of user but it is not essential.

Comment: suggest you consider completely separating these. have a separate log in page going to separate controllers. any methods or functions that the two groups share can be called from models.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use the codeigniter _remap function, just place it in your controller with some logic:

```
    function _remap($methode){
      // do something
}
```

A better solution is to have a basecontroller, which you include in every controller and expend it. In this basecontroller you put the access-control and the complete basic stuff.

Comment: will this redirect to any of the functions in same file? Like if the user_type is employee i just call the employee function?

Comment: You can call every methode in the class (same file).